# How can I sample data using ESP32 ADC and send over Bluetooth Classic to Android device?

Tags: c++, embedded, esp32, adc, arduino-esp32

sorry if this question is worded poorly -- I am really new to the ESP32 and embedded programming in general and I'm struggling to understand how to do this effectively. I will try my best to organize the problems and my attempted solutions in as organized way as I can manage.

Background:

I am trying to stream data from a mcustm circuit I have made to my android phone. I need to sample multiple channels (ideally at multiple GPIO pins). I am currently using my own Andorid app based on [this](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=de.kai_morich.serial_bluetooth_terminal&hl=en_US&gl=US) app to recieve the data to the phone. That part is working fine, no issues there.

The problem I am having is with the ESP32's ADC.

What I've Tried:

I was able to sample data at ~10kHz using the Arduino framework, but that is by simply calling

[adc1_get_raw](https://docs.espressif.com/projects/esp-idf/en/v4.4/esp32/api-reference/peripherals/adc.html)  in a loop in my code. This really isn't a workable solution, however, because CPu interrupts and such cause the sampling rate to vary -- it isn't sampling at a stable 10kHz. I could not find a good way around this in the Arduino framework, so I tried switching to the ESP-IDF framework to make use of the [Continuous ADC mode](https://docs.espressif.com/projects/esp-idf/en/latest/esp32/api-reference/peripherals/adc_continuous.html) offered through that framework. However, in this framework, I am struggling greatly to get Bluetooth Classic functioning, since I am still a relative beginner.

Does anyone know of any approach to do this in the Arduino framework for the ESP32?

Although I do not think it will be particularly helpful, here is my code.

```
//This example code is in the Public Domain (or CC0 licensed, at your option.)
//By Evandro Copercini - 2018
//
//This example creates a bridge between Serial and Classical Bluetooth (SPP)
//and also demonstrate that SerialBT have the same functionalities of a normal Serial

#include "BluetoothSerial.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <string.h>
#include <driver/adc.h>

using namespace std;

#if !defined(CONFIG_BT_ENABLED) || !defined(CONFIG_BLUEDROID_ENABLED)
#error Bluetooth is not enabled! Please run `make menuconfig` to and enable it
#endif

BluetoothSerial SerialBT;

const int WIN_SIZE = 100;
const int NUM_CHANNELS = 1;
int data[NUM_CHANNELS][WIN_SIZE];// this vairable should contain everything needed to send to client. Can   
                                    

bool state = false;

void setup() {
  SerialBT.begin("ESP32test"); //Bluetooth device name
  Serial.begin(115200);
  pinMode(12, OUTPUT);
  
  uint8_t clockDiv = 127;
  adcAttachPin(36);

}

void loop() {
  
  for (int i = 0; i < WIN_SIZE; i++){
    data[i][0] = adc1_get_raw((adc1_channel_t) 36);
  }

  for(int i = 0; i < NUM_CHANNELS; i++){
    
    for(int j = 0; j < WIN_SIZE; j++){

      uint8_t byte1 =  data[i][j] & 0x000000ff;
      uint8_t byte2 = (data[i][j] & 0x0000ff00) >> 8;
      uint8_t byte3 = (data[i][j] & 0x00ff0000) >> 16;
      uint8_t byte4 = (data[i][j] & 0xff000000) >>  24;
      
      SerialBT.write(byte4);
      SerialBT.write(byte3);
      SerialBT.write(byte2);
      SerialBT.write(byte1);

     
      state = !state;
      digitalWrite(12, state);//measure sampling frequency with oscope
    }
  }
  
 

  

  /*
  if (SerialBT.available()) {//reciever
    Serial.write(SerialBT.read());
    Serial.println("That ran");
  }
  */
}
```

I really appreciate any help. Thank you!

Comment: Should not `data[i][0] = adc1_get_raw((adc1_channel_t) 36);` be `data[0][i]`?

Comment: Is your only problem achieving a stable 10kHz sampling rate with accurate timing and low jitter? That's what [timers](https://docs.espressif.com/projects/arduino-esp32/en/latest/api/timer.html) are for. Set up a HW timer to fire at 10 kHz. Attach to this timer an interrupt handler which samples the ADC. Post the sampled value to the main loop through a [FreeRTOS queue](https://www.freertos.org/a00018.html). Read the value in main loop, then process it as required (I suspect even classic Bluetooth will not handle 10000 samples per second 1 B at a time, so consider some batching or aggregation).